# How to control and clear the print spooler in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: printing, hp

Sometimes my printer stops printing and the output is held in the queue.

I usually solve the problem by restarting; but, is there a way to stop and restart the print spooler instead?

Comment: See that command `cupsenable` Oh, and printers automatically get disabled when/if the connection is dropped.

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two ways:

The graphical way: Point your browser to [the CUPS Admin Page](http://localhost:631/)
http://localhost:631/

The command line way: Begin with a lot of reading, `man -k cups`, plus these `man` pages: `lpr(1)`, `cancel(1)`, `lp(1)`, `lpadmin(8)`, `lpoptions(1)`, `lpq(1)`, `lprm(1)`, `lpstat(1)`, and the  CUPS Online Help (http://localhost:631/help)